# edit the last input of react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using react-select and just notice that when I already have value in the input field (either by user type or by choosing the option in menu list), then I blur the input then focus at it again - trying to edit my last input - its just start over from the beginning, not continue from the last character of the input. I just found this [issue](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/1558) in the author's github. Its been raised from 2 years ago and still an open issue. Is there really no workaround to achieve this?

Comment: That seems like a library specific issue which has had no suggestions nor attention from the author on the matter since 2017. Someone would have to fork the project and implement their own fix.

Comment: @KenoClayton alrite, I ask here just hoping maybe someone has workaround for this but not submit/suggest yet to the author. thanks for ur reply

Comment: No problem, hopefully someone finds a workaround soon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend you to use controlled props `inputValue` and `value` pair with `onChange` and `onInputChange` like the following code:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      inputValue: "",
      value: ""
    };
  }
  onInputChange = (option, { action }) => {
    console.log(option, action);
    if (action === "input-change") {
      const optionLength = option.length;
      const inputValue = this.state.inputValue;
      const inputValueLength = inputValue.length;

      const newInputValue =
        optionLength < inputValueLength
          ? option
          : this.state.inputValue + option[option.length - 1];
      this.setState({
        inputValue: newInputValue
      });
    }
  };
  onChange = option => {
    this.setState({
      value: option
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Select
          options={options}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
          inputValue={this.state.inputValue}
          value={this.state.value}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In react-select v1 the props `onSelectResetsInput` set to `false` was doing this job but I guess for v2 you will need to do the trick.

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/4q83rj2954).

Comment: dear @Laura, thank you so much for your help. Seems like you know a lot of things about react-select. Ur suggestions works great. But, when user select option, then start typing, then delete what users already type, it shows the last option that selected by the user, not clear all the value. So, I do some modification in here: https://codesandbox.io/s/8zpzqzyp62. Also, I wanna ask more, if you dont mind

Comment: Please shoot @Akza my example was a draft for you to start with but tell me

Comment: in above link, the modified code, is it possible to also make the typing start from the end of the character after user select an option? the current condition is, typing will continue if the last action is input-change. So, I tried to change the inputValue in onChange event to make user could edit from the last char after doing select-option. But, unfortunately, it seems not working. Cause, when I select-option, the selected option is not displayed, but when I focus to the input again, then the value suddenly change as the selected option value