# How can I continue typing after I select an option with react-select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

After the user selects and option for the dropdown (or creates one with `Creatable`) I want to allow them to continue to type on top of their selection. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [edit the last input of react-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54819925/edit-the-last-input-of-react-select)

Comment: Hi @Laura, thanks for the link. In the example it doesn't seem to work like what I need though. I can't start typing at the end of the selected input.

Comment: Could you provide some example or design to help me to understand what you need ? Thanks

Comment: All I need is that after picking the option I can append more to it. Let's say I select "Consulting" from the dropdown, I want to be able to extend it to "Consulting/Architecture" by typing without having to create an entire new "Consulting/Architecture" option.

Comment: I see two different use cases; 1/ you select an existing option, 2/ you create an option but in both you want `Consulting` to still exist and `Consulting/Architecture` to have the same `value` or `Consulting` will be replaced by `Consulting/Architecture` ?